# "Foundation" framework can be used in AppleScript on Yosemite but not Mavericks

Tags: applescript, server

I've written an AppleScript library that makes use of the "Foundation" framework.
On one computer (with Mac OS X Yosemite), everything runs fine. On my other computer (which runs Mac OS X Mavericks), I'm getting an error.

When digging deeper to check what the issue is, it seems that the "Foundation" framework is not being found or something. When looking in `/System/Library/Frameworks`, I can see that the framework is there though.

On Yosemite, this script works as expected:

```
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions    
set startup_disk to path to startup disk as text
```

On Mavericks, the same script returns the following error:

```
error "Can't get framework \"Foundation\" of «script». Access not allowed." number -1723 from framework "Foundation"
```

What do I have to do make my script run on both Mavericks and Yosemite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper AS-ObjC integration only arrived in 10.10. To support 10.9, you have to put all the ObjC stuff in a script library and then load that script into your regular script to call it. Or, if it's a standalone applet, create it using Script Editor's Cocoa-AppleScript template.

Or, y'know, you could just upgrade your 10.9 boxen to 10.10. Given how quickly Apple drops support for older OS versions, it's best to stay current as much as you can.